# Need Jquery Carousel [slider animation] with HTML and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, carousel

i need a jquery plugin where i want to load the module by default as HTML and upon clicking more link it should load the rest of the content via AJAX and then previous button should be enabled.

Currently when i google i can get lot of plugin which just load either via AJAX or Animation [by hidding the rest of the content]. But for performance issue i don't want to load all the content at one shot and then animation. So i want to load the 5 li's and upon clickiing "More" it should start loading the remaining content but it should also animation.

Could someone help me on this?

-- Bala

Answer (score -1):

My advice to you would be to customize the jCarousel according to your needs. Specifically, when you render the page initially you can include the initial 5 elements of your carousel. Then, in the carousel's onchange event, once you reach the last slide you can use AJAX to pull in the additional images.

Depending on your needs, using jCarousel driven by a flat JavaScript array you could save some load time as the image URLs would be rendered in the original markup, but not downloaded by the browser until they are added to the visible portion of the carousel. No AJAX required. [Here's a demo](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_javascript.html).

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your quick respond, i need to try with onchange event. But my issue is not with image, actually its an whole content which i need to wrap inside the li's and append into the ul, something similar like facebook where upon clicking more button i want to get additional data from backend and scroll the container and then load the respond.current when page load i can the module will get intialized and if i try to load more content via ajax its not able to scroll. Not sure your idea of onchange will work i need to try.

Comment: @user563030 Have you reviewed [this AJAX example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax.html) yet? It looks like you need to make sure to update the size (length) of the carousel whenever a new item is added via AJAX.